# how to show Image slider for long time

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, timer

I am trying to show the image slider for long time where I already used timeout for every image to display. 
But now I want to image slider in this case also:

1.The system should not go the sleep mode if we are not using the system, it
   should show the image slider until I close the browser.

2.The system should not go to the screensaver mode, it should show the image
   slider until I close the browser.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
.mySlides 
{
display:none;
}
</style>

<body>

<h2 class="w3-center"></h2>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" style=""width='962px';height='565px';frameborder='0'"">
  <img class="mySlides" src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" style="width='100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="Desert.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="Hydrangeas.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
    {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }

    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length)
     {
        myIndex = 1;
     }    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: setTimeout(carousel, 5000);  Increase the time limit between each slides

Comment: Thanks for replying. It will work on browser only but when I am opening  in browser shows the images for every 2 seconds but after 3 minutes my system or pc is going the sleep mode and showing the system screen saver.  I want to disable the system time in my code and show the images for long time until I close the browser.

Comment: Looks like a bit of a hack, but https://github.com/ivanmaeder/computer-sleep looks like it could be promising.